# Using Shell Script, search 2 closest, element of 2nd column in file2 for every entry of 2nd column in file1 and append elements of column1 in file1

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have two files file1 and file2 (space separated), both contain 2 columns. Column 1 and column 2 of the file1 is Id and weight(float value). Similarly file2 has Id1 and weight(float value). Using shell command, how to find the 2 closest, distinct elements of 2nd column in file2 for every entry of 2nd column in file1 and append corresponding elements of column1 in file1 ?

file1

```
1 10.0
2 12.1
3 5.2
4 13.0
```

file2

```
15 11.1
10 12.3
17 2.1
12 15.5
11 7.0
```

Expected o/p

```
1 15 10
2 10 15
3 11 17
4 10 15
```

Comment: You have two files which are space separated?

Comment: Say f1 has Column1: 1 2 3 4 and Column2: 10.0 12.1 5.2 13.0. And f2 has Column1: 15 10 17 12 11 and Column2: 11.1 12.3 2.1 15.5 7.0. I want my output AS FOLLOWS: f1 row1: 1 15 10 row2: 2 10 15 row3: 3 11 17. row4 : 4 10 15 12

Comment: Please, give an example. Impossible to understand what you want. (Strangly looks like a problem of CodinGame...)

Comment: Sorry  @Caduchon . See my recent comment. I have given a simple example. Let me explain, file1 and file2 contain only 2 columns (sample data given). Lets start with row1 of file1, the 2nd element of row1, i.e. 10.0, finds 2 closest elements in column 2, i.e. 11.1 and 12.3 in file2. Hence, the solution for row 1 in file1 becomes 1 15 10(we can overwrite row 1 or throw in other file) where 1 is the id already given as a first column, 15 and 10 are the elements of first column in file2 corresponding to 11.1 and 12.3 (selected closest element). Similarly we have to do with other rows of file1

Comment: @DevAnand : edit your initial message with a clear example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cat file1

```
1 10.0
2 12.1
3 5.2
4 13.0
```

cat file2

```
15 11.1
10 12.3
17 2.1
12 15.5
11 7.0
```

*command* : **awk -f script.awk file2 file1**

**script.awk**

```
#! /bin/awk -f
function abs(val) {
    return val < 0 ? -val : val
}
ARGV[1] == FILENAME{
    a[$1] = $2;
}
ARGV[2] == FILENAME{
    inf = 2^16;;
    one=inf; diffOne=inf;
    two=inf; diffTwo=inf;
    for(i in a){
        new = abs($2 - a[i]);
        if(diffOne > new ||  diffTwo > new){
            if(diffTwo >= diffOne && diffOne > new ){
                two = one; diffTwo = diffOne;           
                one = i; diffOne = new;

            } else {
                two = i; diffTwo = new;
            }
        }
    }
    if(one == inf){
        one = ""    
    }
    if(two == inf){
        two = ""    
    }
    print $1,one,two        
}
```

**output**

```
1 15 10
2 10 15
3 11 17
4 10 15
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much @chet.